# OUTLOOK REST API Declining an Event using Node.js

Tags: node.js, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am trying to decline the event created using **Outlook** **REST API**. I had the id of the
 event which was created. My request includes Node.js Code :

```
var body =JSON.stringify(
    {
        "Comment": "Sorry, maybe next time!",
        "SendResponse": "true"
    });
    var options1 = {
                host : 'outlook.office365.com',
                port : 443,
                method : 'POST',
                headers : {
                        'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)   
            },
            json : body,
            path : '/api/v2.0/me/events/EVENT_ID_RECEIVED/decline'   
                }
     };
var str=""; 
     var apiCall=https.request(options1,function(response){

        response.on('data',function(chunk){
            str += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end' , function(){
            console.log("data received is : "+response.data);
            console.log("value is : "+str);
        });
        response.on('error', function(e) {
                      console.log("error received : "+e.message);
               });

    });
    apiCall.write(body);
    apiCall.end();
```

**I have checked that the event was present but still this error came.**

**Sample Request**

```
POST //api/v2.0/me/events/GeneratedEventIdWhileCreatingCalender/decline HTTP/1.1
Host: outlook.office365.com    
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9c925f4a-58df-4409-ca51-278590cfddd1    
{"Comment":"Sorry,maybe next time!","SendResponse":"true"}
```

**Sample Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Max-Age → 86400
Cache-Control → private
Content-Type → application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Date → Fri, 18 Dec 2015 05:02:29 GMT
OData-Version → 4.0
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-BEServer → HK2PR0301MB1154
X-BackEndHttpStatus → 404
X-CalculatedBETarget → HK2PR0301MB1154.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com
X-DiagInfo → HK2PR0301MB1154
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
request-id → 6ab4e13e-f8bd-45c8-a80a-c31f8c580141
```

**Sample Response Body**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store."
  }
}
```

Comment: Mohit - Can you please include an example failed request and response including headers (except authorization header), so we can investigate?  This should work, and the data I have asked will help us investigate.

Comment: Hi @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT i have updated the question with sample request and response , one more thing i would like to mention is that when i call the same api with just replacing the auth token with the moderator's auth token the response comes fine that moderator can't decline the event he created which is correct.

Comment: Thanks, Mohit.  We will investigate and post an answer.

Comment: Per our investigation, the problem is that the event ID you are trying to decline isn't found in the user's mailbox.  Are you using the event ID from the organizer's mailbox, to decline the same event in an attendee's mailbox?  That would fail since the event ID is different in the attendee's mailbox.

Comment: Ok i got the problem, I was using the id which was returned in the response for creating an event , so according to you the id for the event on the attendee's side will be different so we can't use the same id for declining that event. So how can we use REST API to decline the event because we dont know the id for the attendee's event.

Comment: I posted a workaround as an answer, and hope that it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property called iCalUid that is the same for an event both in the organizer's and attendee's mailbox.  However, it looks like $filter using this property isn't yet supported. We will look into adding this.  In the meantime, if you know other details of the event such as start time and end time, you can ask for all events during that timeframe, and confirm you are declining the correct event by comparing iCalUid property of the event in the organizer's mailbox with iCalUid property of the event in the attendee's mailbox.